# Find average visits by unique users every 1 hour

Tags: mysql

I have a table with Places and a table with Visits.

Tables:

```
Place(place_id(pk))
Visit(v_id, user_id, timestamp, place_id(fk))
```

I want to find out how many visits a Place has on an average every 1 hour over the entire Visits table by unique user_id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count every user only once per distinct hour you can group them with `DATE(timestamp), HOUR(timestamp)`

```
COUNT(DISTINCT user_id, DATE(timestamp), HOUR(timestamp))
```

To get the number of distinct hours you can use

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, MIN(timestamp), MAX(timestamp))
```

or

```
COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(timestamp), HOUR(timestamp))
```

which is probably slower but might be more accurate.

Then use a division to get the AVG:

```
SELECT place_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT user_id, DATE(timestamp), HOUR(timestamp))
     / TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, MIN(timestamp), MAX(timestamp)) AS avg_visits_per_hour
FROM Visit
GROUP BY place_id
```